# Is there an example of a Proof of Work Substrate chain?

Tags: consensus, proof-of-work

I am aware of this [`sc_consensus_pow`](https://paritytech.github.io/polkadot-sdk/master/sc_consensus_pow/index.html#) crate but I am wondering if anyone can point to some up to date implementations of it.

Comment: Great question. very intrested to see up to date PoW implementation on top of PolkadotSDK.

Answer (score 2):

Kulupu is a Proof-of-Work blockchain based on the Substrate framework.

You can find more information about Kulupu at: https://github.com/kulupu/kulupu

Answer (score 0):

you might be also interested in https://github.com/Polkadot-Blockchain-Academy/Academy-PoW/